# Rotating ImageView in Android < API Level 11

Tags: android, static, imageview, rotation, drawable

So in API Level 11 Google introduced the ability to rotate an ImageView (Yay, after they introduced the possibility to Animate such a rotation, yay smart thinking, yay!)

But how should I go about to rotate an ImageView using e.g. API level 8? I can't use setRotation() as described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started with creating BitMap and rotating the canvas/matrix, however this was not a good solution. Finally ended up just swapping the drawable if conditions are met. I should say this is an ExpandableListView where cells are reused when drawing.

```
if (isExpanded) {
        ImageView view = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.quickactions_button_normal_down);
    }

    if (!isExpanded) {
        ImageView view = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageView);          
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.quickactions_button_normal);
    }
```

I'm not usually a Android developer but I'm really amazed that it is possible to animate a rotation, but not statically set the rotation of a drawable. Logically the first is a subset of the second and not the other way around.

Answer (score 8):

[RotationAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html) was present since Api level 1

```
RotateAnimation animation = new RotateAnimation(from, to,
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
animation.setDuration(1);
animation.setFillAfter(true);

imageView.startAnimation(animation );
```

Comment: Yes. This will still show as an animation even though the duration is set to 1. Also using this in an ExpandableTableView where cells are reused upon drawing makes it somewhat costly and the "fast" animations looks really weird when scrolling the list. I ended up just swapping the drawable.