# Rotating Android ImageView in API 10 (Without using Animation)

Tags: android, imageview

I want to rotate an ImageView toward specific pivot and with special degree. I searched in Google and found some solution about this, but I didn't find complete answer about this (like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634540/rotating-imageview-in-android-api-level-11)).

I tried to use this code, but `ImageView` didn't rotate! Just the background of it rotates (without rotating view rectangle)

```
public class ImageViewCustom extends ImageView {
    public Context M_context;

    public ImageViewCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.M_context = context;
    }

    public ImageViewCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.M_context = context;
    }

    public ImageViewCustom(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.M_context = context;
    }

    public float xPivot;
    public float yPivot;
    public float degree;

    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(degree, xPivot, yPivot);
        super.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

So, how can I rotating ImageView without using `Animation` and just with overriding or adding rotate methods to `ImageViewCustom` ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score -1):

```
Bitmap bmp = arrow.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(direction);
Bitmap bmpRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(),bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
iv.setImageBitmap(bmpRotated);
```

iv being the imageview and direction the degrees in whicht the bitmap needs to be rotated.

Comment: It just rotates the background of ImageView, not ImageView.

Comment: true but depending on your needs it could be efficient, just trying to help