# setRotationY() width API10 in Android

Tags: android, animation, rotation

I am looking for a method / algorithm to do the equivalent of setRotationY() (which is available from the Android API 11), but with the API 10.

Thank you for your help.

**Update, Answer:**

Use the Android library http://nineoldandroids.com/ by @JakeWharton (thanks Chris.Jenkins)

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 10)
    this.mBehindView.setRotationY(180);
else
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this.mBehindView, "rotationY", 0, 180).setDuration(0).start();
```

Comment: Would RotateAnimation() work for you? See [this][1] SO thread.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634540/rotating-imageview-in-android-api-level-11

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I had seen this post before asking my question, this solution does not work in my case. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know we are not a LinkFactory but @JakeWharton spent time back porting the AnimationFramework from API11.

Checkout [nineoldandroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/).

Example:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "rotationX", 0, 90).setDuration(3000).start();
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know JakeWharton was doing this library and the funny part is that NineOldAndroids is already integrated into the project ActionBarSherlock that I use in my project. But it is not enough in my case. So I added this project and now everything works. Thank you very much :)

(Sorry for my english, I'm french)

Comment: yeah the ABS internal version is cut down to do the actionbar animations only. Glad can be of help.

Comment: This is the best solution I found for android10, all other solutions either reset the position of the view (because the view wasn't actually being rotated the canvas was or something like that) or weren't supported in android10.  Thanks for posting.